# git bash first runs the scanf() before the first printf() function

Tags: c, printf, scanf, git-bash

I am doing a simple C program that accepts input and display some number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, value;
    char sign;

    printf("Please Enter Your Number1:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Please Enter Your Number2:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    value = num1 + num2;
    sign = '+';
    printf("%d %c %d = %d\n", num1, sign, num2, value);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc as compiler.

So the process is there is a text that asks for input, then input two numbers and display the result.

Now, if I compile and run my code in windows cmd, It works perfectly. No problem at all.

But, if I compile and run using git bash, it asks first for numbers before displaying the prompt that asks for number. It is like it runs the `scanf()` first before the first `printf()` function.

Do you know why? I am just curious why it gives different result

first runs the `printf()` then `scanf()` function.

Comment: The `printf()` is still run first, just text stuck in the `stdout` buffer.  Adding a `fflush(stdout);` between `printf("Please Enter Your Number1:\n");` and `scanf("%d", &num1);` may help.  IIRC, it is a git bash implementation problem for the I/O interface and not a C problem, yet I am not certain.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: It may be preferable to request line buffering with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` at the start of the program instead of using `fflush`. Then this code to work around the problem is confined to one piece of code at the beginning of the program instead of scattered throughout wherever terminal I/O is done.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agreed, that looks preferable.  Yet IMHO, it remains an implementation git bash bug.  Unclear why it is not fixed yet.